# Maximal monotone operator without convex domain?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, examples-counterexamples, monotone-operator-theory

I'm looking for an example of a (multi-valued) maximal monotone operator $A$ mapping a Banach space $X$ into its dual $X^*$ such that the domain $D(A)=\{x\in X: Ax\neq\emptyset\}$ is not convex. Preferably, the example should be simple (maybe with $X=\mathbb{R}^2$).

Thanks a lot in advance for suggestions

Comment: What do you mean by $\{x\in X: Ax\neq\emptyset\}$?  Do you mean $A x \neq 0$?  Why would $Ax$ be a set?

Comment: Since $A$ might be multi-valued (written as $A:X\rightarrow 2^{X^*}$, $A:X\rightrightarrows X^*$ or $A\subset X\times X^*$), $Ax$ is a subset of $X^*$ for every $x\in X$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convex subdifferential of a proper convex lower semicontinuous function defined in a Banach space is a maximal monotone operator (that is a result of Rockafellar).
There are several examples of subdifferentials without a convex domain, the one written below being taken from Rockafellar's book "Convex Analysis" on page 218.

Let $f(\xi_1,\xi_2)=\max \{g(\xi_1),|\xi_2|\}$, where $g(\xi_1)=1-\xi_1^{1/2}$, if $\xi_1\ge 0$,  $g(\xi_1)=+\infty$, if $\xi_1< 0$.

The domain of $f$ is the right closed half-plane, and f is subdifferentiable
everywhere on this half-plane except in the relative interior of the linesegment joining $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$.

You can build your own example. Take into consideration that for $\mathbb {R}^n$ all maximal monotone operators have the closure of their domains convex.

Comment: Perfect :). This kind of example was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!!!